# Equivalent of X2V for converting schema.org data of a person to a vcard

Tags: html, schema, vcf-vcard, microformats

I have my contact information marked up as a hcard and use the [H2VX](http://h2vx.com/vcf/) service to allow users to download my contact information as a vcard. However, since Google, yahoo etc have decided to embrace [schema.org](http://schema.org/) I thought I would too. Does anyone know of an equivalent converter to H2VX that uses schema.org data rather than microformats?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

microdata.js is a jQuery plugin that works with Live Microdata Tool, which offers hCard (and other data) conversions from HTML5 Microdata. as far as offering the converted hCard for download, i don't think that functionality is native, but it's open source, so go for it.

microdata.js: https://gitorious.org/microdatajs/

live microdata tool: http://foolip.org/microdatajs/live/